# Pre-condition not working

Tags: vdm++

I'm trying to create a simple 'signup' method.

```
-- Creates a new account
public signup: String * String ==> ()
signup(username, password) == (

    -- create user
    dcl user: User := new User(username, password);

    -- add user
    users := users union {user};
)
pre (let u in set users in u.username <> username);
```

The problem I'm having is with the pre-condition. How can I write the pre-condition 'username is unique'? (ie there is no `user` in `users` where `user.username = username`)

Note: `users` is a `set` of `User`

Edit: `pre (username not in set users.username)` is what makes most sense to me, but this doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a "forall". Your precondition wants to say that "for all of the users' usernames, the new user's name is not equal to them". An alternative would be to generate the set of existing usernames with a set comprehension, and then say the new username is not in that set.

Let us know if the syntax for the above isn't obvious.

Comment: Thank you! The ``forall``solved it - ``pre (forall user in set users & user.username <> username)``. I'm not sure about the ``set comprehension`` though - could you please show me an example of how to do it that way?

Comment: The set comprehension approach is more along the lines of your original thought, but you can't say `users.username` to access the set of all users' names. Instead you need a set comprehension to build it. So that would be `username not in set { u.username | u in set users }`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!